# Which IT fields / IT specializations are most suitable for 100% remote work as a freelancer/contractor/self-employed?

Tags: contracts, web-development, working-from-home, project-management, remote

I would like to know which IT specializations are most suitable for 100% remote work as a freelancer / self-employed. Both in theory and in practice.

How to find clients and companies that are okay with freelancers working 100% remotely from day 1?

Bonus points if the IT specialization allows you to work (mostly) alone / run a one man show.

Answer (score 3):

I've been a remote freelancer for twenty years now and it enabled me to travel the world. Personally, I'm a web/software developer and technical writer. Other opportunities for 100% remote work would be graphic design, web design, blogging, and to a lesser extent server/network administration. Of course, there is also data entry, but you'll have a hard time supporting yourself that way. Best of luck!